# How to combine two for loops

Tags: python, for-loop

Lets say i'm trying to print 0 to 25 and 75 to 100.
Right now I have:

```
for x in range(0, 26):
    print(x)
for x in range(75, 101):
    print(x)
```

Is there any way to combine these into a single for loop that lead to:

```
print(x)
```

?

Something along the lines of:

```
for x in range(0, 26) and range(75, 101):
    print(x)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need the [`itertools.chain()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain):

> Make an iterator that returns elements from the first iterable until it is exhausted, then proceeds to the next iterable, until all of the iterables are exhausted.

```
from itertools import chain

for x in chain(range(0, 26), range(75, 101)):
    print(x)
```

Works for both Python 2 and 3.

Comment: Just to add to @alecxe answer: If you have a list of lists (or any iterable) you can use from_iterable.
i.e.: **list_ = [iter1, iter2, ...]** then: **for x in chain.from_iterable(list_)**
A nice use is to flat a list of lists idly.

Answer (score 1):

Using List Comprehension:

```
[i for j in (range(0, 26), range(75, 101)) for i in j]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for x in list(range(0, 26)) + list(range(75, 101)):
    print(x)
```

You can concatenate two lists by adding them.

Comment: Note that it would fail with `unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'range' and 'range'` on Python 3.x.

Comment: You can wrap in `list(range(x,y))`

Comment: Ahh. I missed the print(x) syntax indicating they are using 3. I will amend shortly.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do it with list comprehension and a single line, if you don't want to import anything. You basically add all the numbers to a list, then print the list as a long string with newline characters after each number.

```
print("\n".join([str(x) for x in range(0,101) if x < 26 or x > 74]))
```